# Issue with 'translate' animation method of 'Titanium.UI.2DMatrix'

Tags: android, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

I was just creating a slide out control using Appcelerator Titanium.

**What I have done:**

I added a button on the view and added it on the window.

```
// Create a Button.
var Animate = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : 'Animate',
    height : 'auto',
    width : 'auto',
    top : 'auto',
    left : 'auto'
});

// Listen for click events.
Animate.addEventListener('click', function() {
     var matrix = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix();
     if(flag)   //Initially the flag is set to true
     {
        matrix = matrix.translate(100,0);
     }
     else
     {
        matrix = matrix.translate(0,0);
     }
     flag = !flag;
     var a = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
        transform : matrix,
        duration : 1000,
        //autoreverse : true,
        //repeat : 3
    });
    self.animate(a);
});

// Add to the parent view.
self.add(Animate);   //Here self is my view
```

**Expected Output**

- Clicking on the button will slide out the view
- Clicking the same button will reset the view

**Actual output:**

- Clicking on the button will slide out the view
- Clicking again on the button not triggering any action
- If I click on the initial position of button it will reset the view

### Screenshots:

**Initial Screen**

[image: Initial Screen]

When I click on button, is **Slide Out**:

[image: Slide Out]

When I click to reset, **Issue** happens:

[image: Issue]

Comment: @Downvoter please add comment, so that I can improve my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a lot of methods, but nothing helped me.
At-last I did the following and it worked.

Instead of adding animation to view I added that to it's window and changed the code little bit like.

```
var firstView = new FirstView();
self.add(firstView);
var xy = 0;

// Create a Button.
var Animate = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : 'Animate',
    height : 100,
    width : 100,
    top : 0,
    left : 0
});

// Listen for click events.
Animate.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var xy = 0;
     var matrix = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix();
     if(flag)
     {
        xy = 100;
        matrix = matrix.translate(100,0);
     }
     else
     {
        xy = 0;
        matrix = matrix.translate(0,0);
     }
     flag = !flag;
     var a = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
        duration : 1000,
        left:xy
    });

    a.addEventListener('complete',function()
    {
        firstView.left = 0; 
    });

    self.animate(a);  //self is the parent window
});


// Add to the parent
firstView.add(Animate);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug, but I do know that the use of the `auto` for sizing is deprecated or at least not recommended, and I'm sure its even less recommended when doing transformations.

> 'auto' specifies that the view should choose either FILL or SIZE behavior. In 2.0, the behavior of the 'auto' value is specified by the UI Composite Layout Spec. This value is not recommended for new development and will be deprecated in the future.
>   On Mobile Web and Tizen, 'auto' always selects SIZE behavior.

Also, auto is not a valid entry for the `top` and `left` position arguments. Why not try:

```
// Create a Button.
var Animate = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : 'Animate',
    height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
    width : Ti.UI.SIZE,
    top : 0,
    left : 0
});
```

But as I said this could be a bug.

Comment: I tried this, no change, it's not the issue. Please check my third image. Also there is no need of -100, if I add that it'll go to other side

Comment: Oh sorry, that is weird, try setting the button to anything but `auto` which is deprecated behavior

Comment: Edited the question (well, replaced it really, with more info)